# How to create windows GUI in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface

I'm sorry if the question is stupid and naive but still: how one can/should develop gui apps for windows in VS using native c++? I'd like to avoid using CLR and .NET stuff in the project. There are 2 obvious way: use heavy and monstrous MFC or code using API without any visual support, which seems also a bad choice for tricky ui. I wonder if there are   other ways to create gui in VS?

Comment: A lot of people use a framework like Qt these days. But your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: A lot of people use a framework like wxWidgets these days.  Research "GUI frameworks for Windows"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Win32 API which is a bit more complicated or use other external libraries that are easier such as gtk, wxWidgets, QT and others, but Win32 API is better because you will understand the operation of the windows and not have to download any library, but usually the codes made with Win32 API are higher than those made with external libraries. Using Win32 API you need to create the window class, event loop and other manually way.

I think QT is the easiest because the interfaces are created in graphical environments.

See these:

http://qt-project.org/

http://www.gtk.org/

And this tutorial about QT:

http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/